# How to delete columns from file 1 which is not there is file 2 using VBScript?

Tags: excel, vbscript

File 1 has - Date, Time, TimeZone, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, CustomerAddress, PhoneNumber, Country, Product, OrderNumber, CreationDate, BatchNumber

File 2 has - Date, Time, TimeZone, Country, OrderNumber, BatchNumber

Delete columns from File1 which are not there in File2.
I want to make programmatic so that if File 2 changes with more column, same code should work. Note: File 2 columns list is always subset of file 1.

Trying to compare two excel files.

Here is my code with comments

```
Sub deleteIrrelevantColumns(strXl, strXlTemplate)
    Dim currentColumn
    Dim newCurrCol
    Dim colTemplate
    Dim colXlCount

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objXl = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strXl)
    Set objXlTemplate = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strXlTemplate)
    Set objXlTemplateWS =  objXlTemplate.Sheets(1)
    Set objXlWS = objXl.Sheets(1)
    objXlWS.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    objXlTemplateWS.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    objExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

    colXlCount = objXlWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count 
    colTemplateCount = objXlTemplateWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    currentColumn = 1

    'Create an array of the size equal to column count
    ReDim columnHeading(colXlCount)

    'Copy the Column heading from Excel file to an array
    For i  = 0 To Ubound(columnHeading)
        columnHeading(i) = objXlWS.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
        currentColumn = currentColumn + 1       
    Next
    'Logic to compare and remove columns
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed some of your original code and added comment. I also added the logic how to compare and delete the column that are not in your template. I'm sure there is a better way of doing it, but I coded the way for easy understanding.

Hope it helps.

```
Dim currentColumn
Dim newCurrCol
Dim colTemplate
Dim colXlCount
Dim strXl           As String
Dim strXlTemplate   As String

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objxl = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strXl)
Set objXlTemplate = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strXlTemplate)
Set objXlTemplateWS = objXlTemplate.Sheets(1)
Set objxlws = objxl.Sheets(1)
objxlws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
objXlTemplateWS.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

colXlCount = objxlws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
colTemplateCount = objXlTemplateWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count

currentColumn = 1

'Create an array of the size equal to column count
'Note: Changed ReDim columnHeading(colXlCount) to ReDim columnHeading(colTemplateCount-1) _
I want to say you should save the Template Column Name into array so you can compare to the ActiveWorkBook

ReDim columnheading(colTemplateCount - 1)

'Copy the Column heading from Excel file to an array
For i = 0 To UBound(columnheading)
    columnheading(i) = objXlTemplateWS.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
    currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
Next
'Logic to compare and remove columns

Dim IntCol      As Integer  'for Column reference
Dim EndCol      As Integer  'Last Column Number Reference
Dim BlnDel      As Boolean  'Indicator for whether should a column be deleted.

EndCol = objxlws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For IntCol = EndCol To 1 Step -1

    BlnDel = True 'set default in the beginning of the loop

    For i = 0 To UBound(columnheading)
        If objxlws.Cells(1, IntCol) = columnheading(i) Then
            BlnDel = False      ' Set to False for any match column to avoid being deleted.
        End If
    Next
        If BlnDel Then
            'objxlws.Columns(IntCol).Delete                      'For Real
            Debug.Print objxlws.Cells(1, IntCol) & " Delete"     'For Test
        End If
Next

objxl.Close
objXlTemplate.Close
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and updating the code. I am getting object error for "Columns.Count" in the line EndCol = objxlws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Comment: @srini, I tested the code and I ran fine with me. I don't think there is an syntax problem. You can try to replace it with EndCol = 5 or any number to debug it.